# .htaccess domain redirect - TLD agnositc

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect short.tld to longer.tld  regardless of whether the tld is dev or com and depending on what was requested.

So like this...

```
short.dev should redirect to longer.dev
short.com should redirect to longer.com
```

So far I have this which is working (for .dev):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?shorty\.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://longer.dev/$1 [R=301,L]
```

... but how can I make the .dev in the RewriteRule TLD agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to make it `sot-of tld agnostic`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?short\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://longer.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Realized the problem and fixed. Please check the edited code.